# Sampling a smaller set of line graph points without losing trends

Tags: java, math, graph, charts, line

Given a set of X/Y co-ordinates ([(x,y)] with increasing X(representing a timestamp) and Y representing a value/measurement at that timestamp.

This set can possibly be huge and i would like to avoid returning every single point in the set for display but rather find a smaller subset that would represent the overall trend of the measurement(some level of accuracy loss in the line graph will be acceptable).

So far, i tried the simple uniform sampling of measurement skipping points at uniform interval, then adding the max/min measurement value to the subset. While this is simple, It doesn't really account well for local peaks or valleys if the measurement fluctuates often.

I'm wondering if there are any standard algorithms that deal with solving this type of problems on server side?

Appreciate if anyone has solved it or know of any util/common libraries solving such problems. I'm on Java, but if there is any reference to standard algorithms i might try to implement one in Java.

Comment: Just saying, the tag "graph" is not applicable here. Graph is a data structure, it's not an x and y plane like we all used in school.

Comment: You might want to look at the Douglas-Peucker algorithm, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: @systemdebt I ended up using Douglas-Peucker algorithm

Comment: Thanks for confirming. How's your experience with it so far? @opuser1

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a general answer to this question. It all depends on how your datapoints are stored, what properties your chart has, how it is rendered etc.

But as @dmuir suggested, you should check out the Douglas-Peucker algorithm. Another approach I just thought up could be to split the input data into chunks of some size (maybe corresponding to a single horizontal pixel) and then using some statistic (min, max, or average) for rendering chunk. If you use running statistics when adding data points to a chunk, this should be O(n), so it's not more expensive than the reading on of your data points.